# How to apply css class in runtime when class is outside the loop

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'll explain. I've a 1D array of objects. I want to loop through this array. There is a property in that object i.e. `widgetType`. Depending on this type only I've to decide the grid size in css. Here's the template:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div *ngFor="let widget of staticKpi">
        <p>widget.value</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Right now I'm getting 3 columns because of this line `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;`. I want to set the number of columns based on `widgetType` because different widget types have a different arrangement. For example two widgets can have 6 values but one is 2X3 and the other type can be 3X2. I want something like this:

```
<div <div [ngClass]="{'classname' : condition}"></div>
    <div *ngFor="let widget of staticKpi">
        <p>widget.value</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it is outside the loop. Whats the best approach for this. Please help.

Comment: if you want to have dynamic css based on object in a loop, you have to have the css/class inside the loop. If you dont want to have extra elements/styles/layouts, you can put *ngFor in a `<ng-container>` which doesn't puts anything in the DOM. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-ng-container-element

Comment: Can you share staticKpi data structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest approach is to calculate the style in TS upon receiving the widgets data, e.g. (I'm doing a lots of guessing here, since no actual code was provided, but it should get you on track):

```
staticKpi: Widget[];
gridContainerStyle: string;

getData(): void {
    this.kpiService.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.staticKpi = data;
        this.gridContainerStyle = calculateStyle(data);
    });
}

private calculateStyle(widgets: Widget[]): string {
    // Implement actual logic based on passed widgets
    const columnsValue = 'auto auto auto';
    
    return {
      'display': 'grid',
      'grid-template-columns': columnsValue,
      'padding': '10px',
    }
}
```

And in template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="gridContainerStyle">
    <div *ngFor="let widget of staticKpi">
        <p>widget.value</p>
    </div>
</div>
```